# How to send a specific index of an array and array itself on click to another html page / js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As seen in the image I have index.html (it has a index.js) that loads multiple images using a json image array and on edit icon click I need to send the clicked image info to another site let's say: index1.html (it has a index1.js) so it would load on an editor using canvas...

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ0w0.png)

I can't seem to get it pass with session or local storage because it gives me the last result of the index instead of a specific index of the array related to the click event. I don't know if I need to use a server to upload all the images or not, currently I don't use a server.

```
var k=0;
var filesArr = [];
var newArr = [];
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    $(input.files).each(function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(this);

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            filesArr.push(e.target.result);
            newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filesArr));
            var jsonedImgArr = [];
            var file = {};
       // manually create a new file obj for each File in the FileList
            for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
                var source = newArr[i];
                var name = input.files[i].name;
                var id = i;
                file = {
                    'id': id,
                    'name': name,
                    'src': source
                }
                //add the file obj to your array
                jsonedImgArr.push(file);
            }//$("#previewImg") is an id="" inside a div
            $("#previewImg").append("
                 <div class='container1'>
                     <img class='img-fluid1 img1 ' src=" + jsonedImgArr[k]['src'] + ">
                     <p class='title'>" + jsonedImgArr[k]['name'] + "</p>
                     <div class='overlay'></div>
                     <button type='button' class='responsive-width' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
                         <i style='color:white;' class='button far fa-edit'></i>
                     </button>
                     <div class='modal fade' id='myModal'>
                        <div class='modal-dialog modal-xl'>
                            <div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'> 
                               <button type='button' class='close responsive-width' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class='modal-body'>
                                <iframe id='frame' style='width:100%;height:100%;' src='index1.html'></iframe>
                            </div>
                            <div class='modal-footer'>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary responsive-width' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                            </div>
                            </div></div></div>");
                            k++;
       }
```

```
//the src should be instead of the '' down here
fabric.Image.fromURL('', function (oImg) {
    add(oImg,75,98);
});
```

I need to get the index and the array to the file "index1.js" so I could edit save and update the existing json array on "index.js" as it will appear on "index.html" as seen in the image.

Comment: you could use query string to pass a id/value to the second site

Comment: @Marc ummm can you elaborate plz?

Comment: @Alaluf just make your stuff in index(js,html) and when a user click on one image, redirect the user to index2.html?image=<your image id>. then you can get that query string in js and do what ever you want with it.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two pages? Are they ran from same origin? How gets your popup open? Are you doing something like `open('index2.html')`? The code you provided has no relation with the question...

Comment: @Kaiido it's all inside the append function... i'm using modal with a button for the editor and inside i use the iframe to stay on the same page so i need it to be without redirection to another page only to another html inside the current page so the html2 would be the editor for the specific picture you click the button on...